# what's the advantages of using the data structure of static linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

In this question, static linked list is defined as the following:(c++ code)

```
template<typename T> struct Node{
    T elem;
    int next;//yes, int, which points to the index of the next element in the array.
};
Node static_linked_list [SOME_SIZE];
//some initialization code omitted.
```

So in this kinds of linked list, it is static because its size is allocated during the array initialization. The link is achieved through the field, `int next`, which points to the index of the next element.

What's the advantages of this data structure over the pointer(or, reference) based linked list? What's its application? As far as I know, the static one has scoped lifetime, and may be used when implementing `malloc`. But its `int next` doesn't seem to have less memory expenditure than pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what this particular structure is being used for, but the unusual technique does offer the ability to behave like a linked list while using a capped and *fixed, pre-allocated* memory block that doesn't need to be managed besides updating indexes in the elements as required. (Note that of course the index field doesn't *have* to "point" to the *next* numeric index, it can point to any index, thus the "list" does not need to be stored in semantic order.)

It's faster to "remove" an item than if were a simple array (which would require shifting later elements). Adding items is trickier and is obviously limited by size of the overall element array, but could be sped up with some look-aside bookkeeping. I'm not sure under what exact circumstances you'd decide you needed this particular data structure over a different kind of list. My guess is you'd be under pretty cautious memory constraints where predictability was king: think gaming consoles, embedded devices, drivers/operating system layers, etc.